# ZingChart line chart with x-axis only with only existing value

Tags: zingchart

Is it possible to have x-axis only on Zing Line Chart and also only display existing points on x-axis ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are looking for a line chart with the y-axis hidden? I will update my answer once you see this chart.

```js
var myConfig = {
  type: 'line',
  scaleY:{visible:false},
 series: [
  {
   values: [35,42,67,89,25,34,67,85]
  }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({ 
 id: 'myChart', 
 data: myConfig, 
 height: '100%', 
 width: '100%' 
});
```

```css
html, body {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#myChart {
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 min-height:150px;
}
.zc-ref {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <!--Assets will be injected here on compile. Use the assets button above-->
  <script src= "https://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="myChart"><a class="zc-ref" href="https://www.zingchart.com">Powered by ZingChart</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks :), sorry forgot to update the thread... I was able to achieve the same...